# How do I find username by email using github rest api?

Tags: github-api

I need to remove a member from the organization, but I have only email id of the user and the organization name.

One Solution I found is to fetch all the members of the organization, find the user with matching email, then remove that user from the organization using the username.

Any straightforward solution to this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your organization member public email/login using [GraphQL API V4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) :

```graphql
{
  organization(login: "your-org") {
    members(first: 100) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
      edges {
        node {
          login
          email
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then filter the email, for instance using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
org="your-org"
email="your-mail@gmail.com"
access_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $access_token" \
     -X POST \
     -d '{ "query": "query { organization(login: \"'"$org"'\") { members(first: 100) { pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } edges { node { login email } } } } }" }' \
     https://api.github.com/graphql | \
     jq -r --arg email $email '.data.organization.members.edges[] | select(.node.email == $email) | .node.login'
```

In the example above you will need a personnal access token with scope `read:user` or `user:email`

You can then remove membership using [Rest API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#remove-a-member)

```bash
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Token $access_token" "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/members/the-user-to-remove"
```

Note that this won't find the user if the email isn't public on the user's profile